# Unable to get data in proper format

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am unable to parse data in PHP from MySQL.

Here's my code

```
    <?php
     header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
     // array for JSON response
      $response = array();   

      echo 'भगवान';

      require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

       // connecting to db
       $db = new DB_CONNECT();

       // get all products from products table
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM create_event") or die(mysql_error());

       // check for empty result
       if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
       // looping through all results
       // products node
       $response["create_event"] = array();

       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
           // temp user array
           $product = array();
        $product["id"] = $row["id"];
        $product["desc"] = $row["desc"];
        $text;

        array_push($response["create_event"], $product);
    }

    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;


    echo json_encode($response);
     } else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
     }
?>
```

It's my database, I have set all the collation in utf-8 ci format but still not working:

[image]

I have tried all possible solutions and help online and have gone through popular posts and answers and also have set browsers settings to support Hindi lang but still displaying `?` marks in output. Here is the output format

```
    भगवान{"id":"1","desc":"???? ??????"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

Use this after connecting to database or before using any select statement.